# R Shiny: how to reduce the font size of menu sub-item in sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css, r, shiny

I am trying to reduce the font size of menu sub-item in the sidebar of my Shiny app.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test Dashboard"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu (
    menuItem("Test",startExpanded = TRUE,
             menuSubItem("Dashboard", tabName = "tab"),
             menuSubItem("Link")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar { font-size: 12px; }")),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab",
            box(title = "Table", width = 10, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
            )
  )
  )

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(tabledata)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, by using `tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar { font-size: 12px; }"))`, I only got main menu item font size reduced, when I expand the main item, the font size of menu sub-item is still default.

Please advice and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Test Dashboard"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu (
    menuItem("Test",startExpanded = TRUE,
             menuSubItem("Dashboard", tabName = "tab"),
             menuSubItem("Link")
    )
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tags$style(HTML(".main-sidebar { font-size: 12px!important; }
                   .treeview-menu>li>a { font-size: 12px!important; }")),
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab",
            box(title = "Table", width = 10, status = "warning", DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(tabledata)
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Try to use google Chrome and the inspector to navigate to the element. There you can see it! Be careful. If the font size comes from AdminLTE, you have to overwrite it with `!important`, otherwise nothing changes

[image]